# How to maintain active/active endpoint with Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Recently AWS had a biggest outage with S3 on US-east-1. We would like to expand to multiple regions now deploying lambda and S3 data to other regions. I would like to retain **one single url** that can detect if the region has an outage and forward the call to the active region. If both regions are active, closest region will receive the request.

I tried with AWS Route53 and it did not help with **https**. Since Cloudfront cannot accept the same cname on more than one distribution.

[image: Load Balance across regions]

Comment: As far as I can tell, you've found the crux of the problem with CloudFront, each Fully Qualified Domain Name can be the alias of exactly 1 Distribution. If you go to API Gateway, and have Custom Domains with ACM, then it uses CloudFront again. Route 53 Routing and Health Checks work at the DNS level, so any services need to handle traffic for the same domain.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at it. Alternatively, CloudFront should give an option for region specific origins or rules that can it can direct traffic.

Comment: *"region specific origins"* --- You can, if you use Route 53 latency-based routing *behind* CloudFront (on the origin domain name) so that the origin server selection is based on the nearest region to the CloudFront edge that handles the request... but when the origin is S3, this requires proxies in EC2 to rewrite the `Host` header in the request so that it matches the bucket.  R53 health checks solve the back-end routing by taking a failed region out of the latency-based routing.  It can totally be done, just not without EC2.

Comment: Problem with EC2 comes with scaling, high availability, maintainance and one more point of failure.